# Why reset button does not work here?

Tags: html, forms

In the below html code,

```
<h1>Our Contact Form</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="process_form.php" method="get">
            <p>
            Title: <input type="radio" name="title" value="mr"> Mr 
                   <input type="radio" name="title" value="mrs"> Mrs
            </p>
            <p>
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" size="15" name="first_name">
            </p>
            <p>
                Sur name:<br>
                <input type="text" size="15" name="surname">
            </p>
            <p>
                Gender:
                <select>
                    <option value="select">Select Gender</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter"> Subscribe to my news letter
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>        
        </form>
```

If I comment `form` element(only), in the above code, then, `Reset` button does **NOT** reset the data.

Can somebody help me understand, why?

Comment: i tried in my system its working only

Comment: your code is working fine..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rktLvd6u/)

Comment: yes, works fine. Try autocomplete="off" for input type=text elements

Comment: I've tried it also and as the above said - It works.

Comment: @Lal But your code has form element, try this updated [code](http://jsfiddle.net/rktLvd6u/1/), this does not reset, as mentioned in above  query.

Comment: yes yes..i misread your question..sorry..

Comment: @Lal You did not misread, I forgot to mention **NOT**

Comment: Remove comment bro From Form tad

Comment: Give me one reason why you're forced to *"comment"* `form` tag, and I shall give you a clear answer. You need to use JavaScript to handle form submission.

Comment: @AdamAzad I want to comment `form` tag and receive&submit data using `input` & `option` elements, because I would like to understand, if I can reset&submit data using html(only) without using `form` element.

Comment: You need JavaScript for this, and a pretty comprehensive one ;)

Answer (score 2):

> If I comment form element(only), in the above code, then, Reset button does not reset the data.

The reset functionality as far as I read your question is part of a form data. By commenting the form element this function will not work. It is like if you comment the form and try to submit ?!?  If you have a return value in a function and comment this function(only) will this work ?

**The input element with a type attribute whose value is "submit" represents a button for submitting a form.**

**The input element with a type attribute whose value is "reset" represents a button for resetting a form.**

Comment: Does submit functionality also not work without `form` element?

Comment: Yes sure
The reset method resets the values of all elements in a form (same as submit one). http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms13.htm

Comment: Can't I use submit and reset functionality without `form` element?

Comment: You can but have to use JS for example or other external logic which will apply for this actions